# custom select show selected value after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to build my custom select but I am stucked. Everything works fine until page refresh. I am a jQuery begginer and I found this on codepen.

```js
$('select').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

    $this.addClass('select-hidden');
    $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
    $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
    $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

    var $list = $('<ul />', {
        'class': 'select-options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        $('<li />', {
            text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
            rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
        }).appendTo($list);
    }

    var $listItems = $list.children('li');

    $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
    });

    $listItems.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
        $list.hide();
        //console.log($this.val());
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        $list.hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.select-hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
 .select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #005ca5;
  height: 40px;
  width: 155px;
}
 .select-styled {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
 .select-styled:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-color: #005ca5 transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 10px;
}
 .select-styled.active {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
 .select-styled.active:after {
  top: 9px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #005ca5 transparent;
}
 .select-options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
  border-top: 0px;
}
 .select-options li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-indent: 15px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
 .select-options li:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #005ca5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="color" id="frm-statusForm-form-color" class="select-hidden">
<option value="#E19244">Orange</option>
<option value="#666666">Grey</option>
<option value="#886666" selected="">Brown</option>
<option value="#2FB483">Green</option>
<option value="#005CA5">Blue</option>
<option value="#71DFFC">Light blue</option></select>
```

I am working with php, when I select a value, it saves the selected value. 
In source code u can see in default select selected value, but not in my custom select. 
**Select is automatically generated so I can't change HTML.**
So the only way is to change jQuery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [localeStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for such implementation, localeStorage have `.setItem()` and `.getItem()` methods where you can set values to be used across your app even after a refresh,

changes:

```
var styledText = $this.children('option').eq(0).text();
if(localStorage.getItem($this.attr('name'))) {
  styledText = localStorage.getItem($this.attr('name'));
}
$styledSelect.text(styledText);
```

and in `$listItems.click`:

```
$listItems.click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
  $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
  $list.hide();
  localStorage.setItem($this.attr('name'), $(this).text());
});
```

here is a working [jsfildde](https://jsfiddle.net/mamounothman/6e5oagfy/13/), also a snippet, but it will not work here since stackoverflow snippets are sandboxed and can't access localStorage:

```js
$('select').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

    $this.addClass('select-hidden');
    $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
    $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
    
    var styledText = $this.children('option').eq(0).text();
    if(localStorage.getItem($this.attr('name'))) {
      styledText = localStorage.getItem($this.attr('name'));
    }
    $styledSelect.text(styledText);

    var $list = $('<ul />', {
        'class': 'select-options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        $('<li />', {
            text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
            rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
        }).appendTo($list);
    }

    var $listItems = $list.children('li');

    $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
    });

    $listItems.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
        $list.hide();
        localStorage.setItem($this.attr('name'), $(this).text());
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        $list.hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.select-hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
 .select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #005ca5;
  height: 40px;
  width: 155px;
}
 .select-styled {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
 .select-styled:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-color: #005ca5 transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 10px;
}
 .select-styled.active {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
 .select-styled.active:after {
  top: 9px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #005ca5 transparent;
}
 .select-options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
  border-top: 0px;
}
 .select-options li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-indent: 15px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
 .select-options li:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #005ca5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="color" id="frm-statusForm-form-color" class="select-hidden">
<option value="#E19244">Orange</option>
<option value="#666666">Grey</option>
<option value="#886666" selected="">Brown</option>
<option value="#2FB483">Green</option>
<option value="#005CA5">Blue</option>
<option value="#71DFFC">Light blue</option></select>
```